# css for fading overlaid video controls?

Tags: javascript, css

In some DVD/Video players, the controls for play/pause/volume/etc are overlaid on top of the video itself in a box.   The controls fade in when you move the mouse, and then, after some delay, fades back out (so you can enjoy the video again).

I am wondering -- how to create this effect using CSS?  Is there a way to reset the fade-out timer on events other than body mouse move?

Comment: Are you kidding? Why doesn’t this have more upvotes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have the following HTML template:

```
<div class="player">
    <div class="controls">Controls go here</div>
</div>
```

It is possible if you use CSS `transition-delay`: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7sBwA/

```
.player {
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.controls {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2em;
    right: 2em;
    bottom: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0;
}
    .player:hover .controls {
        pointer-events: auto;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .player:not(:hover) .controls {
        transition-delay: .5s;
    }
```

However, if you want better browser support, you should use JS instead.

When using jQuery, you can exploit the `.delay()` method when using jQuery effects, such as `.fadeOut()` in our example: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/g7kge/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".player .controls").hide();
    $(".player").hover(
        function(){
            // Mouse enters. Fade in controls
            $(this).find(".controls").fadeIn();
        },
        function(){
            // Mouse leaves. Delay controls fade out by 1000ms
            $(this).find(".controls").delay(1000).fadeOut();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to control the fade-out timer using CSS with:

```
-(prefix)-transition: all <duration> ease-out <delay>;
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Gm9q/1/).

Comment: `-??-kit` is so wrong... I suppose you mean `-(prefix)-transition`. And the timing in the `transition` property is not the delay, but the time duration of the transition.